# Find the stock coverage month in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have below data where I am trying to find till which month the available stocks are good.

I have demands from March to June and Stocks in various stages in FG/WIP/RM, the formula should compare the demands with stock levels and show till which month the actual coverage happens.

Example : FH+WIP+RM total stock is 10+15+20=45 , This can cover march, april and May, so the result should be may

Similarly for part 2 result would be march.

I need help to find a formula in Coverage until column, which will sum FG+WIP & RM and calculate till which month the stock covers.

| part name | march | april | may | june | FG | WIP | RM | Coverage until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Part 1 | 10 | 11 | 23 | 36 | 10 | 15 | 20 | Result : May |
| Part 2 | 12 | 14 | 13 | 18 | 8 | 12 | 0 | Result:March |
| Part 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I know this can be achieve through Index and match but someone i am struck at formula to get the running total and corresponding column name.

Comment: Have you looked at the use of index() with match()? There are lots of examples on here.

Comment: Yes I did but failed lot of times, issue is with finding the running sum and identifying the corresponding column name which is previous column of the sum > the stock levels

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Not exactly sure on what you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please use this tool: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: @Aztec-3x5 Sorry for not being elobrate , I just explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following array formula (spill the entire result for all rows), *assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. In cell `J2`, put the following formula:

```
=LET(dem, F2:F3+G2:G3+H2:H3, in, B2:E3, h, B1:E1, BYROW(HSTACK(in,dem),LAMBDA(x, 
 INDEX(h, SUM(N(SCAN(0, DROP(x,,-1), LAMBDA(ac,y, ac+y)) <= TAKE(x,,-1)))))))
```

or without `LET` function (shorter, but more difficult to read/explain it):

```
=BYROW(HSTACK(B2:E3, F2:F3+G2:G3+H2:H3), LAMBDA(x, INDEX(B1:E1, SUM(N(SCAN(0, 
 DROP(x,,-1), LAMBDA(ac,y, ac+y)) <= TAKE(x,,-1))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

where `dem` is the demand. We iterate over all rows using `BYROW` but adding as last column the demand. For each row (`x`) we calculate the cumulative sum via `SCAN` of the first columns removing the demand `(DROP(x,,-1)`, then we do the comparison with the demand (last column, i.e. `TAKE(x,,-1)`) and sum the number of times it satisfies the condition, which corresponds with the index position of the header (`h`). Finally, we use `INDEX` to find the corresponding header value.

**Note**: It is also possible using `MMULT` and the unit lower triangular matrix (`tri`) instead of `SCAN` for doing the cumulative sum, but it is a more verbose approach:

```
=LET(dem, F2:F3+G2:G3+H2:H3, in,B2:E3, h, B1:E1, n, COLUMNS(h),
 tri, N(SEQUENCE(n) >= SEQUENCE(,n)), BYROW(HSTACK(in,dem), 
 LAMBDA(x, INDEX(h, SUM(N(MMULT(tri, TOCOL(DROP(x,,-1))) <= TAKE(x,,-1)))))))
```

Comment: This worked for me David =BYROW(HSTACK(B2:E3, F2:F3+G2:G3+H2:H3), LAMBDA(x, INDEX(B1:E1, SUM(N(SCAN(0, 
 DROP(x,,-1), LAMBDA(ac,y, ac+y)) <= TAKE(x,,-1))))))             Thanks a lot , this is advanced stuff which i need to learn. Any links for me to learn such advance features?

Comment: @Chetan it takes time, just read the Microsoft specification of the functions I used and try to see the intermediate result so you understand better each steps. Try to read similar excel answers from other members of this community. The following helped me a lot: JvdV, ScottCraner, P.b., JosWoolley, Harun24hr

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
I2: =INDEX(Sheet4!$B$1:$E$1,MATCH(2,1/(SUM(Sheet4!$F2:$H2)-SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(Sheet4!$B2,0,0,,SEQUENCE(4)))>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron, but it picks the last demand ( June demand) but doesnt show the result

Comment: @Chetan Huh? It shows in the last column (where the formula is) exactly the same results as you show in your example. Did you expect something different?